# Where can I read about the multinoulli distribution?

Tags: terminology, probability-distribution, softmax

I encountered the term **multinoulli distribution** in the following sentence from [Chapter 4: Numerical Computation](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html) of the deep learning book.

> The softmax function is often used to predict the probabilities
> associated with a **multinoulli distribution**.

I am guessing that multinouli distribution is any probability distribution that has been defined on a **random variable taking multiple values**. I know that SoftMax function is used in converting a vector into another vector of the same length with probability values that signify the chance of input falling into that particular class.

Suppose $C$ is a random variable with support $\{c_1, c_2, c_3, \cdots, c_k\} $. Then I am guesssing that any probability distribution on $C$ is a multinouli distribution. SoftMax is an example of such multinouli distribution that uses the expression $\dfrac{e^x}{\sum e^x}$ for calculating probabilities.

Is my guess correct about multinoulli distribution? The reason for my doubt is that I never came across the word multinoulli and I cannot find even on internet. If my guess is wrong, where can I read about multinoulli distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a description of this distribution (which is also known as **categorical distribution**, which you probably already heard of) in section 2.3.2 (p. 35) of the book [Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective](http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf#page66) (by K. Murphy). You can also find there and in the previous section a description of the related Bernoulli, binomial and multinomial (the most general of the four) distributions. The word *multi**noulli*** is used in order to remind you that this distribution is a generalization of the Ber**noulli**.

In any case, this is how you may remember these four probability distributions.

- [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution): you throw a coin only **once** ($n=1$), and a coin has **$k = 2$ outcomes** (heads or tails)
- [Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution): you throw a coin $n$ times, where $n$ can be greater than $1$, and a coin has **$k = 2$ outcomes**
- [Categorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution): you throw a dice, with **$k$ sides** (e.g. a side may be $1$ or $5$), where $k$ can be greater than $2$, only **once** ($n=1$)
- [Multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution): you throw a dice, with **$k$ sides, $n$ times**

So, these are all discrete probability distributions, with an associated probability mass function (p.m.f). In all of them, we have two parameters $n$ (the number of trials of the experiment) and $k$ (the number of outcomes).

I don't think it is correct to say that a softmax is a probability distribution. The softmax is a function used to compute the probabilities that you associate with a categorical distribution, i.e. you use the softmax to produce a [probability vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_vector) (although some people will say that the softmax produces a [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution)), as the excerpt that you quote states. In principle, I think you could use other functions to do that (an alternative to the regular softmax, *sigsoftmax*, is proposed in [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/file/9dcb88e0137649590b755372b040afad-Paper.pdf), section 3.3, p. 6). So, the *softmax* is used to *model* a categorical distribution, but I wouldn't say it's a categorical distribution. You can find an explanation of why the softmax is used instead of e.g. just normalizing by the sum [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17325/2444) (and a long list of probability distributions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions)).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a definition on Wikipedia [Categorical distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution).

In short, it is a generalization of the Bernoulli distribution to multiple variables (multivariate Bernoulli distribution).

Comment: I think most of this answer is correct, except for "multiple variables" and "multivariate Bernoulli distribution". The categorical distribution is a generalization of the Bernoulli, but for a categorical variable, i.e. a variable that can take 1 of $k$ possible values (where $k = 2$, in the case of the Bernoulli).